# Delegate Methods of NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    [self.responseData setLength:0];(URL1)
    self.jsonData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];(URL2)
    self.genderData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];(URL3)
}
```

I want to send multiple url at a time what the process to receive response..?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);
    NSError * error;
    id result = (NSMutableArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"DATA LOAD ERROR");

    }
    else
    {
        if([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {

            titlesArray = result;
        }
        else
        {
            titlesDic = result;
        }

    }

    [self genderURLMethod];


}
```

This is another Delegate Method

Comment: You might want a use 2 different instances of NSURLConnection and check which one is it in 'connectionDidFinishLoading:'.

Comment: Another way to do this is to use AFNetworking, it uses completion blocks to handle the response. This can be better when using multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `NSURLConnection`, I tend to go one of two ways.

1. Always use a different class for each delegate. That way the delegate instance only has to worry about 1 URL.
2. Use `[[connection originalRequest] URL]` to distinguish between the different URLs.

Example:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *URLString = [[[[connection originalRequest] URL] absoluteString];
    if ([URLString isEqualToString:MY_URL_1]) {
        // Handle the response for the first URL.
    } else if ([URLString isEqualToString:MY_URL_2]) {
        // Handle the response for the second URL/
    }
}
```